Linear regression in R: Receiving different results based on dummy coding
I am performing a linear regression with one continuous predictor and one categorical (two levels) predictor. I have included the categorical factor as a named factor ("Control" and "BD") and also, just to check, as a dummy-coded factor ("0" and "1"). Running the same command for a linear regression yields results that differ for the continuous predictor, but are the same for the categorical factor and the interaction.
I have read in a csv with "Group" and "GrpNum" as separate columns. The "Group" column lists the group assigned to each case (Control, BD), while the GrpNum column is a dummy code of this factor (0 = Control). I get a different result, but only for the effect of the continuous predictor, depending on which categorical factor I use -- even though they are exactly the same.
I tested with a different dummy code (1 = Control, 0 = BD) and found that this reproduced the problem. However, when I check if any of these factors are ordered, R reports that they are not.
Because the effect is different, I do not know which analysis to trust as "correct." I understand that the order may be changing the intercept, but that's not super important. What I am concerned about is the different value for the effect of ContX in the examples below.
> lmtest1 <- lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum * ContX, data = data)
> summary(lmtest1)

Call:
lm(formula = Outcome ~ GrpNum * ContX, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.1330 -3.7301  0.0448  4.1718 11.1743 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  -13.7037     4.2195  -3.248  0.00202 **
GrpNum        14.0967     5.1699   2.727  0.00865 **
ContX          0.4670     0.1364   3.423  0.00120 **
GrpNum:ContX  -0.4179     0.1639  -2.550  0.01372 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.111 on 53 degrees of freedom
  (9 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2008,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1556 
F-statistic:  4.44 on 3 and 53 DF,  p-value: 0.007413

Note that the coefficient for ContX is 0.4670 and that this is a significant effect.
> lmtest2 <- lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data = data)
> summary(lmtest2)

Call:
lm(formula = Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data = data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.1330 -3.7301  0.0448  4.1718 11.1743 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)     0.39294    2.98729   0.132  0.89585   
GrpNum2       -14.09666    5.16990  -2.727  0.00865 **
ContX           0.04908    0.09087   0.540  0.59137   
GrpNum2:ContX   0.41791    0.16392   2.550  0.01372 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.111 on 53 degrees of freedom
  (9 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2008,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1556 
F-statistic:  4.44 on 3 and 53 DF,  p-value: 0.007413

The variable "GrpNum2" is the inverse of "GrpNum." The coefficient for ContX is 0.0490 and this is not significant.
> is.ordered(data$GrpNum)
[1] FALSE
> is.ordered(data$GrpNum2)
[1] FALSE
> is.ordered(data$Group)
[1] FALSE

All factors are unordered.
To recreate:
GrpNum1 <- as.factor(rep(c(1,0), 20))
GrpNum2 <- as.factor(rep(c(0,1), 20))
Outcome <- rnorm(40, 0, 1)
ContX <- rnorm(40, 10, 5)
data <- data.frame(GrpNum1, GrpNum2, Outcome, ContX)
lmtest1 <- lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum1 * ContX, data = data)
lmtest2 <- lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data = data)
summary(lmtest1)
summary(lmtest2)


Please provide a seed (set.seed()) when simulating data.

I think you are being confused by the interaction term. With the GrpNum:ContX term present, you can't answer "what is the effect of ContX?", you have to ask "what is the effect of ContX given a certain value of GrpNum?" Here is a toy example where I set the effect of ContX on Outcome to be Outcome = 2.13ContX + 0.78 if GrpNum1 == 1 and Outcome is zero if GrpNum1 == 0. I also added a bit of noise to each Outcome value. ContX looks insignificant and has a coefficient of 0.09 in the first fit in the reprex but it has a tiny p value in the second and the coefficient is 2.05. That is because different levels of GrpNum1 were chosen for the baseline case. Either fit leads to the same predicted values, as shown at the end of the reprex. Neither fit is "right".
If you do a fit with no interaction, you will see that the coding of the categorical variable does not matter (in that case) in the fit results, within a sign.
GrpNum1 <- as.factor(rep(c(1,0), 20))
GrpNum2 <- as.factor(rep(c(0,1), 20))
set.seed(123)
ContX <- rnorm(40, 10, 5)
Outcome <- ifelse(GrpNum1 == 1, ContX * 2.13 + 0.78, 0)
Outcome <- Outcome + rnorm(40, 0, 2)
data <- data.frame(GrpNum1, GrpNum2, Outcome, ContX)
lmtest1 <- lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum1 * ContX, data = data)
lmtest2 <- lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX , data = data)
summary(lmtest1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Outcome ~ GrpNum1 * ContX, data = data)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.6455 -0.9718 -0.1824  1.3611  4.1400 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)    -0.76933    0.98653  -0.780    0.441    
#> GrpNum11        2.17554    1.59435   1.365    0.181    
#> ContX           0.09343    0.09016   1.036    0.307    
#> GrpNum11:ContX  1.96126    0.14254  13.759  6.6e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.949 on 36 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9799, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9782 
#> F-statistic: 584.4 on 3 and 36 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
summary(lmtest2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data = data)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.6455 -0.9718 -0.1824  1.3611  4.1400 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)      1.4062     1.2525   1.123    0.269    
#> GrpNum21        -2.1755     1.5943  -1.365    0.181    
#> ContX            2.0547     0.1104  18.611  < 2e-16 ***
#> GrpNum21:ContX  -1.9613     0.1425 -13.759  6.6e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 1.949 on 36 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9799, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9782 
#> F-statistic: 584.4 on 3 and 36 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
data$Pred1 <- predict(lmtest1, newdata = data)
data$Pred2 <- predict(lmtest2, newdata = data)
head(data)
#>   GrpNum1 GrpNum2    Outcome     ContX       Pred1       Pred2
#> 1       1       0 14.7215204  7.197622 16.19512729 16.19512729
#> 2       0       1 -0.4158346  8.849113  0.05745442  0.05745442
#> 3       1       0 36.1494508 17.793542 37.96650313 37.96650313
#> 4       0       1  4.3379119 10.352542  0.19792178  0.19792178
#> 5       1       0 25.8728384 10.646439 23.28139167 23.28139167
#> 6       0       1 -2.2462172 18.575325  0.96618707  0.96618707

Created on 2024-11-11 with reprex v2.1.1

Equivalence
First note that these two models are equivalent from the viewpoint of having the same predictions and residuals so it is only a matter of parameterization:
all.equal(fitted(lmtest1), fitted(lmtest2))
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(resid(lmtest2), resid(lmtest2))
## [1] TRUE

To be absolutely sure that the model matrices of the two models span the same vector spaces we can check that every column of the model matrix of model 2 is a linear combination of the columns of the model matrix of model 1 and visa versa.  We can do this by taking the deviance (i.e. residual sum of squares) of the regression of each model matrix against the other and checking that it is zero for each regression.  (Due to floating point approximation this will be a vector of small numbers near zero.)
mm2 <- model.matrix(lmtest2)
lm(mm2 ~ GrpNum1 * ContX, data) |> deviance() |> unname()
## [1] 5.467180e-29 2.277255e-31 2.870914e-28 4.338390e-28

mm1 <- model.matrix(lmtest2)
lm(mm1 ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data) |> deviance() |> unname()
## [1] 5.467180e-29 5.693138e-32 2.900138e-28 4.560602e-31

Models
Now let O, g1, g2 and X be the columns. Then the models are the following
O = b0 + b1 * g1 + b2 * X + b3 * g1*X + error
O = B0 + B1 * g2 + B2 * X + B3 * g2*X + error

Converting one model to the other
Since g2 = 1- g1 we can substitute that into second model and collecting terms we have the following where the parenthesized expressions must equal the corresponding coefficients in the first model for the models to be equivalent.
O = (B0+B1) + (-B1) * g1 + (B3+B4) * X + (-B4) * X * g1 + error

We can write this in terms of R where we confirm that parameterizations can be linearly transformed into one another
b <- coef(lmtest1)
B <- coef(lmtest2)

# these are the same

c(B[1] + B[2], -B[2], B[3]+B[4], -B[4])
##    (Intercept)       GrpNum21          ContX GrpNum21:ContX 
##     -0.7693297      2.1755446      0.0934313      1.9612630 

b
##    (Intercept)       GrpNum11          ContX GrpNum11:ContX 
##     -0.7693297      2.1755446      0.0934313      1.9612630 

Convert in other direction
To convert the other way we can substitute into the first model in the same way or invert the matrix corresponding to the correspondence just shown.
m <- matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 0,
  0, -1, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 1,
  0, 0, 0, -1), 4, byrow = TRUE)

# these are equal

solve(m, b)
## [1]  1.406215 -2.175545  2.054694 -1.961263

B
##    (Intercept)       GrpNum21          ContX GrpNum21:ContX 
##       1.406215      -2.175545       2.054694      -1.961263 

As an aside note that it turns out that m is a self inverse so solve(m) equals m.
all.equal(m, solve(m))
## [1] TRUE

demean
If we demean GrpNum* then the coefficients will be the same except for sign and the p-values for the coefficients will be the same too.
data2 <- transform(data,
   GrpNum1 = scale(as.numeric(GrpNum1), TRUE, FALSE),
   GrpNum2 = scale(as.numeric(GrpNum2), TRUE, FALSE)
)

coef(summary(lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum1 * ContX, data2)))
##                   Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)    0.065929548  0.3550531  0.1856893 0.8537308
## GrpNum1        0.939578002  0.7101061  1.3231515 0.1941278
## ContX         -0.003661942  0.0330496 -0.1108014 0.9123893
## GrpNum1:ContX -0.078134995  0.0660992 -1.1820868 0.2449206

coef(summary(lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data2)))
##                   Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)    0.065929548  0.3550531  0.1856893 0.8537308
## GrpNum2       -0.939578002  0.7101061 -1.3231515 0.1941278
## ContX         -0.003661942  0.0330496 -0.1108014 0.9123893
## GrpNum2:ContX  0.078134995  0.0660992  1.1820868 0.2449206

Contrasts
If we specify sum contrasts (contr.sum) then the two approaches give the same coefficients except for sign and they also give the same p-values.
coef(summary(lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum1 * ContX, data, 
  contrasts = list(GrpNum1 = contr.sum))))
##                    Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)     0.065929548  0.3550531  0.1856893 0.8537308
## GrpNum11       -0.469789001  0.3550531 -1.3231515 0.1941278
## ContX          -0.003661942  0.0330496 -0.1108014 0.9123893
## GrpNum11:ContX  0.039067497  0.0330496  1.1820868 0.2449206

coef(summary(lm(Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX, data,
  contrasts = list(GrpNum2 = contr.sum))))
##                   Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)     0.065929548  0.3550531  0.1856893 0.8537308
## GrpNum21        0.469789001  0.3550531  1.3231515 0.1941278
## ContX          -0.003661942  0.0330496 -0.1108014 0.9123893
## GrpNum21:ContX -0.039067497  0.0330496 -1.1820868 0.2449206

anova
If the problem is how to test whether including ContX is significant without regards to the parameterization then this cannot be done by looking at the significance of single coefficients since there is a 2 degrees of freedom difference between the full model and the model without ContX.  Looking at single parameters only considers the difference between models that differ by 1 degree of freedom.  Instead use anova. Here we compare the full model to the model without ContX. We get the exact same answer regardless of parameterization.
anova(lmtest1, update(lmtest1, . ~ GrpNum1))
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Model 1: Outcome ~ GrpNum1 * ContX
## Model 2: Outcome ~ GrpNum1
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     36 29.892                           
## 2     38 31.166 -2   -1.2747 0.7676 0.4716


anova(lmtest2, update(lmtest2, . ~ GrpNum2))
## Analysis of Variance Table
##
## Model 1: Outcome ~ GrpNum2 * ContX
## Model 2: Outcome ~ GrpNum2
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     36 29.892                           
## 2     38 31.166 -2   -1.2747 0.7676 0.4716

Note
In the above we used the code for the input in the question with set.seed(123) .

Added anova section.
